# clarification on logic when creating 100s of tables using sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite

Using winforms, c# , sqlite.

My current app takes in data from text files and stores them in three respective tables. It then uses these tables to give a variety of output based on the user's selection.

Currently this app only deals with one text file but I need to make it process 100s of text files. Ie, read each text file data store it in tables etc.

... Then I well have 3 tables multiplied by the 100s of text files(3 tables for each file).

1) is it possible to maintain this many tables in sqlite?

2) how do I ensure my tables don't just get overwritten by the next file's value? Can someone put sample code for how they would approach this?

Comment: Do these files/tables all have the same structure?

Answer (score 1):

1. SQLite has no limit on the number of tables.
2. Each table must have a unique name.

However, it would be a better idea to normalize your database, i.e., use a single table with an additional column that specifies the original file of the record.